# What is the use of do-while

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

For and while loop can be used anywhere in replace of do-while then why the C language has do-while loop, what is it's real use .

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
do{
statements; 
}
while(condition);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: The body always executes at least once, unlike the other loops

Comment: But I can use while loop by having different condition

Comment: A different, but sometimes more complicated, condition.

Comment: Do-while can be used everywhere instead of for and while loop. So what’s the point?

Comment: @Prince By that reasoning, you don't need both `for` and `while` loops, since you can always replace one with the other.  Even further, you don't need any loop statements at all, since you can achieve the same effect with `if` and `goto` statements.  The point is that the builtin loop statements better match the situations that arise in practice.  Granted, `do` ... `while` is the least commonly used, but it does have its uses.

Answer (score 0):

The main use of using a do while loop
is that even if the condition that you pass is false it will execute the loop at least once.

While Loop: *First condition then execute the code*

Do While Loop: *First execute the code then condition*

Comment: If you wanna know more about it check this out: https://youtu.be/0eamtcMSWAg